# Does Amazon EKS support IPv6 networking?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ipv6, kubernetes, calico

I have been searching for hours, but can't find any direct information on this topic.

Here is what I know:

Calico [can be deployed into EKS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/calico.html)

Configuring IPv6 networking is possible with Calico.

Configuring IPv6 networking with Calico requires the ability to specify [command line arguments](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.7/networking/ipv6) to the Kubernetes components running on the master.

As far as I know, passing arguments to the master components is not supported in EKS at this time.

I need to port an existing EKS application from IPv4 only networking to IPv6-only networking.

I am hopeful that somebody here might have experience doing this.  If so, could you please point me in the right direction? What are my options?

All the best,
-klebs

Comment: Does this question is still valid or you were able to find solution?

Answer (score 2):

As per the [AWS container roadmap](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/398) IPV6 support is not there yet. CNI plugin V2 might support ipv6. However its not in plan as of now.

In general, IPV6 is supported on AWS VPC's.

Answer (score 1):

Native IPv6 support [was recently added to EKS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/amazon-eks-launches-ipv6-support/), however at this time it is only available for new clusters.

Answer (score 0):

Support for IPv6-only clusters was added in Kubernetes 1.9 as an alpha feature, and with version 1.13 the Kubernetes default DNS server changed to CoreDNS which has full IPv6 support.

Calico lets you [disable IPv4 and enable IPv6](https://opsnotice.xyz/kubernetes-ipv6-only/) for pods.

Also according to this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-migrate-ipv6.html):

> If you have an existing VPC that supports IPv4 only, and resources in
>   your subnet that are configured to use IPv4 only, you can enable IPv6
>   support for your VPC and resources. Your VPC can operate in dual-stack
>   mode — your resources can communicate over IPv4, or IPv6, or both.
>   IPv4 and IPv6 communication are independent of each other.

It also explains how to migrate to IPv6.

Please let me know if that helped.